# dictionary key and value in combine with django query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I have a very complicated case for me that I couldn't solve related dictionary function in django.

Here is my data output that I am retrieving via html post messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, data) function:

```
{'id_370': '370', '350_370': 'try_1', '450_370': 'try_2', 'id_397': '397', '350_397': 'try_3', '450_397': 'try_4'}
```

try-1 try-2 try-3 try-4 are the input that I would like to update in my database.

Basically what I want to do is that look for id_ and filter that object with this command `qs = FP.objects.filter(id=i.lstrip('id_')` Till here  (first for loop)it works fine.

What I couldn't do is that another for "for x in val" loop where I am checking the id at the end of the key like _370 and _397 and if that fits that key, I would like to retrieve it's value and update my database if it's length more than 1.

I am trying to do since 2 weeks and read lots of documents but my skills is not enough for solution but I think I am on right path am I not ? I would be very happy if someone enlightens me. :)

Here is my view.py as per below where I am having logic problem

```
 else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.POST.dict()
            data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)
            ids = [k for k in data.keys() if 'id_' in k]
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, data)
            for i in ids:
                val = [b for b in data.keys() if '_' + i in b]
                #messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, val)
                #messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, i.lstrip('id_'))
                qs = FP.objects.filter(id=i.lstrip('id_'))
                for x in val:
                    updates = {}
                    if len(data.values[x]) > 1 and '350_' in data.keys():
                        updates['P_350'] = data.values[x]
                    if len(data.values[x]) > 1 and '450_' in data.keys():
                        updates['P_450'] = data.values[x]
                    if updates:
                        qs.update(**updates)
        return render(request,"index.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the dict contains both IDs and then some values related to those IDs, in the format

- `id_<tid>` = thing id
- `<vid>_<tid>` = a value related to the thing

So something like

```
data = {'id_370': '370', '350_370': 'try_1', '450_370': 'try_2', 'id_397': '397', '350_397': 'try_3', '450_397': 'try_4'}
ids = {k.split('_')[1] for k in data if k.startswith('id_')}

groups = {}
for id in ids:
    groups[id] = {
        k.split('_')[0]: v
        for (k, v)
        in data.items()
        if not k.startswith('id_') and k.endswith('_' + id)
    }

print(groups)
```

converts the data into a more palatable form:

```
{
  '397': {'350': 'try_3', '450': 'try_4'},
  '370': {'350': 'try_1', '450': 'try_2'},
}
```

With that, it should be more straightforward for you to loop over the thing ids and do things with the values:

```
for thing_id, values_dict in groups.iteritems():
    # get thing from database, update it if needed
```

**EDIT:** For instance, to just print everything:

```
for thing_id, values_dict in groups.items():
    for value_id, value_value in values_dict.items():
        print(thing_id, value_id, value_value)
```

prints

```
397 350 try_3
397 450 try_4
370 350 try_1
370 450 try_2
```

Comment: yes you understood totally correct what I want to do and the list that you converted is actually what I am after. Let me work on it to see how can I combine with django database query.

Comment: Thank you so much .One more thing, I need, how can I access in the for loop the id 397  and its value like try_3

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day :)